# Knex subquery to sum data from 2nd table

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

I'm trying to write a query using knex to SUM the votes for each question but am not getting the correct sum.  I can write the subquery in SQL but can't seem to piece it all together. I am a student and not sure if I'm doing something wrong with Knex or if my underlying logic is wrong. Thanks in advance for any help!

My knex query looks like this

```js
return knex
  .from('question')
  .select(
    'question.id AS question_id',
    knex.raw(
      `count(DISTINCT vote) AS number_of_votes`, //this returns the number_of_votes for each question_id as expected
    ),
    knex.raw(
      `sum(vote.vote) AS sum_of_votes`, //something wrong here... E.g., question_id 1 has 3 down votes so the sum should be -3, however I am getting -9
    ),
  )
  .leftJoin('user', 'question.user_id', 'user.id')
  .leftJoin('vote', 'question.id', 'vote.question_id')
  .groupBy('question.id', 'user.id');
```

There are 3 tables that look like:

**user**

- id
- user_name

**question**

- id
- title
- body
- user_id (FK references user.id)

**vote**

- question_id (FK references question.id)
- user_id (FK references user.id)
- vote (-1 or 1)
- PRIMARY KEY (question_id, user_id)

I did manage to write the query as a stand-alone SQL query and verified that it works as expected. This is what I am trying to accomplish in the above knex query:

```sql
SELECT question.id, sum(vote.vote) AS sum_of_votes FROM question LEFT JOIN vote ON question.id = vote.question_id GROUP BY question.id;
```

Comment: Your working query is not joining the `users` maybe this has an effect on the results.
Try to remove the users join from knex and see if the results become correct

Comment: Additional input, your query may sum questions without vote, cause you are joining votes to questions, some questions are not voted yet, the result will be `null`, and probably it mess with `Sum`, try to change the sum statement to  `Sum(IsNull(vote.vote, 0))`.

Comment: hmm neither of those seem to work. I think what is happening is the vote sum is getting multiplied by the number of # of times the question was voted on...Going back to example of question 1 has 3 down votes (expect -3 as vote_sum). It's actually getting reported 3x (once for each instance of a vote on the question) and then summed. But I'm not sure how to make it only report the sum 1x for each question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, broadly your SQL query is correct (after fixing a couple of typos) although as [@felixmosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6539317/felixmosh) points out it has no user information in it: might be tricky to figure out who voted for what! But perhaps you don't need that for your purposes.

Your posted solution will do the trick, but is perhaps not the most efficient query for the job as it involves a subquery and several joins. Here's the SQL it generates:

```
SELECT "question"."id" AS "question_id",
  count(DISTINCT vote) AS number_of_votes,
  (
    SELECT sum(vote) FROM vote
      WHERE question_id = question.id
      GROUP BY question_id
  ) AS sum_of_votes
  FROM "question"
  LEFT JOIN "user" ON "question"."user_id" = "user"."id"
  LEFT JOIN "vote" ON "question"."id" = "vote"."question_id"
  GROUP BY "question"."id", "user"."id";
```

We can take a simpler approach to get the same information. How about this?

```
SELECT question_id,
  count(vote) AS number_of_votes,
  sum(vote) AS sum_of_votes
  FROM vote
  GROUP BY question_id;
```

This gets all the information you were looking for, without joining any tables or using subqueries. It also avoids `DISTINCT`, which could lead to incorrectly counting the number of votes. The Knex to generate such a query looks like this:

```
knex("vote")
  .select("question_id")
  .count("vote AS number_of_votes")
  .sum("vote AS sum_of_votes")
  .groupBy("question_id")
```

You only really need to join tables here if you were looking for further information from those tables (such as the user's name or the question's title).

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to figure this out I finally got it. Here is solution:

```js
return knex
  .from('question')
  .select(
    'question.id AS question_id',
    knex.raw(
      `count(DISTINCT vote) AS number_of_votes`,
    ),
    knex.raw(
    `SELECT sum(vote) from vote WHERE question_id = question.id GROUP BY question_id) AS sum_of_votes`
  )
  .leftJoin('user', 'question.user_id', 'user.id')
  .leftJoin('vote', 'question.id', 'vote.question_id')
  .groupBy('question.id', 'user.id');
```